# CFD numerical methods (FEA, FVM, FDM,…)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid, cfd, numerical-methods

I just read the answer from this question and have a question please:

What I read: Computational Fluid Dynamics (CFD) refers to the use of the numerical techniques to solve fluid dynamical problems. When I say 'numerical techniques', I am referring to a very broad range of techniques, including, but not limited to, Finite Difference Methods, Finite Element Methods, Finite Volume Methods, Polynomial Fitting, Spectral Methods, Boundary Element Methods and so on

Original question link: [What is the difference between FEA and CFD?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14192/what-is-the-difference-between-fea-and-cfd)

My question: how do you know which numerical technique you’re using when you run a CFD simulation? What determines this?

Comment: "Do CFD"? which package are you looking at? What do they say they use?

Comment: Any given package may have access to different types of solver, though I doubt they'd go to a different paradigm. These are selected by statements in the control file for the run. For instance in ADAMS I can switch between FORTRAN or C solvers, which each have their own disadvantages. Similarly in Hypermesh you select the target solver, and the deck is then built for that solver.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you find these things out by reading the documentation for the software package you're using.  If it's a package for which the source code is available, you could also look at the source code.